# задача на вектор

Tags: c++

Сережа и Дима играют в игру.Перед игроками лежат в ряд n карточек,На каждой карточке написано число, причем все числа на карточках различны,Игроки ходят по очереди, первый ходит Сережа. На свой ход можно забрать себе одну карточку: либо самую левую карточку из ряда, либо самую правую. Игра заканчивается, когда в ряду не осталось карточек. Выигрывает тот, у кого в конце игры сумма чисел на взятых карточках больше.
      каждый из них из двух карточек выбирает ту, на которой написано большее число. помогите решить задачу

```
        входные данные
        4
        4 1 2 10
        выходные данные
        12 5
```

Сережа возьмет карточки с числами 10 и 2, таким образом сумма Сережи 12. Дима возьмет все остальные карточки с суммой 5.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, sergo = 0, dima = 0, m, k, c;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> v(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> v[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(v[i] > v.back() - i){
            sergo = sergo + v[i];
            v.erase(v.begin());
        }else{
            sergo = sergo + v.back();
            v.pop_back();
        }

        if(v[i] > v.back() - i){
            dima = dima + v[i];
            v.erase(v.begin());
        }else{
            dima = dima + v.back();
            v.pop_back();
        }

    }

    cout << sergo << dima;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78151/discussion-on-question-by-saba-koguashvili---).

Answer (score 3):

Я бы взял дек и сделал так:

```
int main()
{
    deque<int> d;
    int N, score[2] = { 0 };
    cin >> N;
    for(int i = 0, n; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cin >> n;
        d.push_back(n);
    }
    N = 0;
    while(!d.empty())
    {
        if (d.back() > d.front())
        {
            score[N] += d.back();
            d.pop_back();
        }
        else
        {
            score[N] += d.front();
            d.pop_front();
        }
        N = 1 - N;
    }
    cout << score[0] << " " << score[1] << endl;
}
```

Вы пытаетесь работать с вектором, что неудобно, и в одной итерации цикла обрабатывать (и удалять) сразу 2 элемента, что приводит к ошибке...

Comment: Эх, а я пытался заставить человека самостоятельно отдебажить. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Знаете, этот хоть честно пытался. По крайней мере код хоть туда направлен. А то бывает - задание, после чего исходник или из одного `main(){}`, или явно откуда-то свистнут, потому что решает совершенно не ту задачу - типа, "я работал". А то и вообще - "надо сделать то-то и то-то! [и бегом!!! :)]" Так что в данном случае я не выдержал и решил помочь...

Answer (score 1):

Хм, у меня вышло что-то вроде такого..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> cards;
    int dimaScore = 0;
    int sergeiScore = 0;
    int cardsQnt = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter cards qunatity : ";
    std::cin >> cardsQnt;

    for (int i = 0; i < cardsQnt; i++)
    {
        int card;
        std::cout << "Enter card #" << i << ": ";
        std::cin >> card;
        cards.push_back(card);
    }

    while (!cards.empty())
    {
        //Ход Cережи
        if(cards.back() > cards[0])
        {
            sergeiScore += cards.back();
            cards.pop_back();
        }else
        {
            sergeiScore += cards[0];
            cards.erase(cards.begin());
        }

        //Ход Димы
        if(!cards.empty())
        {
            if (cards.back() > cards[0])
            {
                dimaScore += cards.back();
                cards.pop_back();
            }
            else
            {
                dimaScore += cards[0];
                cards.erase(cards.begin());
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Sergei is : " << sergeiScore << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Dima is :" << dimaScore << std::endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: что значит Вытащить карту справа и слева?

Comment: @SabaKoguashvili, в коде была логическая ошибка. Обновил ответ